# Which is a Better German Translation of "Will"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it "Wunsch", "Wille" or something else?

The context is an original poem. Both the English and German text are mine.

> Wo ist sie, die eine (or jemand)?
>   Die so "schön, und starke sei. (Konjunktiv)
>   Die den Wunsch/Wille und die Fähigkeit
>   Hatte meine Sehnsuchten zu erfüllen..
>
> Where is she, the someone?
>   So beautiful, yet strong as well.
>   Who has the will and ability,
>   My (deepest) longings to fulfill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed both, *"Wunsch*", and *"Wille"* would be correct translations in the context of your poem.

Both seem not to be perfect in this rather romantic setting, where synonyms like *"Bedürfnis"*, *"Drang"*, *"Sehnsucht"*, *"Verlangen"* or even in a poetical sense *"Durst"* may be more emotional.

In my suggestion below I chose *"Lust"* but as it is a bit weaker than *will* this may be open to the poet's intention.

> Wo ist sie, die Eine,
>   die so schön, und doch so stark ist?
>   Die Lust hat und auch Kraft,
>   meine Sehnsucht zu stillen.

In case a rhyme is wanted we may put it like this:

> Wo ist sie, die Eine,
>   schön und stark wie keine?
>   Die Kraft hat und Willen,
>   meine Sehnsucht zu stillen.

Comment: I deliberately used the Konjuntiv SEI to rhyme with eine, and likewise, "Faehigkeit." Are either of them wrong?

Comment: ah! I see - let us rhyme then. I'll add sth in a minute - loses much of poetry in my humble try...

Comment: @Takkat: +1, What a lovely poem, the second one.

Comment: @Takkat: @Gilgili: I have a confession to make. I wrote my English and German lyrics to a FRENCH melody: Gilbert Becaud's "Quand On Est Seul,"

Comment: 'Wille' klingt für mich doch zu berechnend und vernünftig. 'Wunsch' erscheint mir in Herzensangelegenheiten viel besser. Auch die 'Kraft' irritiert mich. Wieso Kraft? Ist der Autor so ein Scheusal?

Comment: @user unknown: Ich bin der festen Überzeugung, dass es gerade bei schwierigen, da poetischen Übersetzungen sehr fruchtbar und für den Fragesteller auch wichtig wäre, wenn sich jeder mit seiner konstruktiven Kritik die Mühe machte, eine eigene, bessere Antwort zu formulieren. Nur so kann ein Wettbewerb aus Antworten enstehen, aus dem sich dann die beste Antwort herauskristallisiert.

Comment: Ja, 'Wunsch' als Wort habe ich ja genannt. Wenn ich aber ganze Strophen übersetze werde ich Urheber - das kann im Interesse des Fragers kaum sein. Oder geht's um 'Kraft'? 'Ability/Fähigkeit' klingt etwas nach Arbeitsagentur. Es geht ums Wollen und Können, und 'Kraft' ist weniger nüchtern, auch wenn es nicht passt. Also eine überzeugende Lösung sehe ich nicht, erlaube mir desungeachtet Kritik. :) Ich habe mich redlich und nach Kräften bemüht. :)